# Eloquent eager loading multiple tables

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to fetch covers of the books that belongs to an author. So far, so good. But it generates a separate query for each book and takes 2 seconds to load a page, I think I'm doing something wrong.

I use eager loading with my comments table (a comment belongs to a user), but since I use polymorphic relations with images table (a image can belong to different kind of other tables, such as user, thing, or group, so I can't use foreign keys in images table since it's not a right convention), I couldn't find a way to achieve the same thing this time.

Image Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Image extends Model
{

    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

Person Model (Author)

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model {
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Thing', 'person_thing');
    }
```

Thing Model (Books)

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thing extends Model {

    public function cover() {
        return $this->morphMany('\App\Models\Image', 'imageable');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    $findBooks = Person::with(array('books' => function($query)
            {
                $query->groupBy('original_name');
            }))->find(52957);

            $allbooks = $findBooks->books;


return view('frontend.index')->with('allbooks', $allbooks)
        }
```

Current View

```
@foreach($allbooks as $allBooks)
    @foreach($allBooks->cover as $value)
        <img class="hund" src="{{$value->link}}" alt="">
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: I've not tried this with an eager loading constraint before, but you can do nested relation eager loading using dot notation. So try `array('books.cover' => function...`. The only thing I'm not sure of is if the `$query->groupBy(...)` then refers to each cover, or each book.

Comment: You could try to lazy eager load the cover relationship via the returned Collection. `$allbooks = $findBooks->books->load('cover');` I'm not sure if the `groupBy` will affect that also, but it's a thought.

Answer (score 2):

From [this post on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/nested-eager-loading-with-constraints)

```
$query->with([
    'child' => function ($q) {
        $q->where(’someCol', ’someVal’); //constraint on child
    },'child.grandchild' => function ($q) {
        $q->where(‘someOtherCol’, ‘someOtherVal’); //constraint on grandchild
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with eager loading or morph to many if your page takes 2s to load, ,Did you install laravel/debugbar to see exactly what takes 2 sec or how many queries u run?